# How to start a process (mysql) in Bazel Sandbox (block-network, macos)

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to start an [embedded mysql](https://github.com/wix/wix-embedded-mysql/) in my java test.
When I run a basic test which starts up the server with the tag `block-network` I get:

> mysql start failed with error: [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on
>   unix socket: Operation not permitted 2017-07-24T17:58:59.952051Z 0
>   [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket:
>   /tmp/5044135838291373301.sock ?

When I remove the tag everything passes. It seems that `/tmp` is writable.

Full reproduction [repository](https://github.com/ittaiz/bazel-block-network-issue/tree/master)
This is on mac os 10.12 with Bazel 0.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try to build a version of Bazel with [this pull-request](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/3444/files) included (just a one-line change) and see if it helps? Bazel is currently blocking UNIX socket communication on macOS when block-network is specified. This change should allow it. I'm not sure yet whether I want to put this behind a flag (e.g. --sandbox-allow-sockets) or just make it the default behavior, but one way or another, I'll make sure that Bazel will support your use case.